# How do I have my repeater's Itemcommand event not do a full page postback?

Tags: asp.net, webforms

In my user control I have the following markup:

```
<div id="pageEditsView" style="margin-left:540px">
    <asp:UpdatePanel runat="server">
        <Triggers>
            <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="PageEditList"/>
        </Triggers>
        <ContentTemplate>
            <asp:HiddenField runat="server" ID="CurrentPageId"/>
            <asp:Label runat="server" ID="EditDisplayLabel" Visible="False">Edits tied to this page:</asp:Label>
            <br/>
            <ul>
                <asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="PageEditList" OnItemCommand="PageEditList_ItemCommand">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <li>
                            <%# ((PageEdit)Container.DataItem).CachedName %> 
                            (<asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" Text="remove" CommandName="remove" CommandArgument="<%# ((PageEdit)Container.DataItem).Id %>" />)
                        </li>    
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:Repeater>
            </ul>
        </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
</div>
```

Whenever I click on the remove link button, it is performing a full page postback instead of just updating this control's panel.  My master page has the following setup:

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" EnablePartialRendering="True" />
```

Other parts of this application (which I inherited, and the old dev who wrote this is no longer around) seems to do partial page updates just fine.  Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: I believe the problem is that the control whoes event is triggered is not the PageEditList but the remove button within it. So you will have to traverse through all the buttons and register all the remove buttons to be asynchronous in the code behind. Maybe use the OnItemCreated Event of the repeater to do this.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try to register the linkbutton [as async postback control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.scriptmanager.registerasyncpostbackcontrol%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), the appropriate place is the [`ItemCreated`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.repeater.itemcreated.aspx) event which is triggered on every (async/full) postback:

```
protected void PageEditList_ItemCreated(Object Sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e) 
{
     if(e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
     {
         ScriptManager scriptMan = ScriptManager.GetCurrent(this);
         LinkButton btn = e.Item.FindControl("LinkButton1") as LinkButton;
         if(btn != null)
         {
             btn.Click += LinkButton1_Click;
             scriptMan.RegisterAsyncPostBackControl(btn);
         }
     }
}
```

Comment: When I do this (either having repeater inside or outside the update panel content i get this error in javascript: ncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined. My link buttons all have an ID displayed when i inspect element.

Comment: I'm puzzled. I'm currently maintaining a WebForms and admittedly it's close to 10 year since I did my last WebForms project. But I cannot remember ever having to do this to get Repeater Itemcommand events to work with an UpdatePanel. On the same form I have a button outside the Repeater, and it triggers the UpdatePanel without any problems.

Answer (score 1):

Add this after ContentTemplate

```
    <Triggers>
        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="PageEditList" EventName="ItemCommand" />            
    </Triggers>
```

Comment: this works just fine for me with `UpdateMode="Conditional"` and `ChildrenAsTriggers="false"` set on the update panel.

Comment: Did not work for me on asp.net 4.0 with ChildrenAsTriggers="true" which I need.