# ASP.Net Repeater, ItemCommand and UpdatePanel Issue

Tags: c#, asp.net, updatepanel, repeater

I have an UpdatePanel, inside this is a Repeater and the Repeater has an OnItemCommand function.  Inside the ItemTemplate of the Repeater is a LinkButton.  Other buttons inside the UpdatePanel operate correctly but the Repeaters buttons causes a Postback.

I discovered I need to register them as an async postback control as per the answer to the question here: [How do I have my repeater's Itemcommand event not do a full page postback?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17641724/how-do-i-have-my-repeaters-itemcommand-event-not-do-a-full-page-postback)

This works but not completely.  For example when the button is clicked it should get the CommandArgument of the button for an ID, retrieve a record, set a hiddenfield and textbox text accordingly and open a ModalPopupExtender which displays this textbox.

I put breakpoints in every line of code on the click function, it gets the command argument ok, loads the record ok, and sets the hiddenfield value and text ok.  When finished the MPE opens up as expected however the TextBox and HiddenField value is blank??

Any ideas as to why despite the code behind showing it should be setting these why the page is not updated correctly?

Comment: show some piece of code to better understand (.aspx and code behind)

Comment: This is just part of a very large screen so difficult to include code, if you want something specific I can add it and strip out unnecessary code.  The fact is my code works it's simply that the Textbox text and Hiddenfield value don't change state on screen after the button click.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like the pop-up doesn't contain an update panel and therefore the values are updated in  the codebehind (server), but not on the client. But like stated, a code sample will clarify.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out I had to manually update the UpdatePanel i.e.

```
updatePanelID.Update();
```

And then textbox/hiddenfield were populated as expected.